# Comparison of CloudFlare's new Argo routing feature

Tags: cloudflare

Does anyone have any experience with or know of any stats on CloudFlare's new [Argo](https://www.cloudflare.com/argo/) intelligent routing feature regarding actual performance improvements before and after enabling it?

Cloudflare themselves provides very little information about it and expected performance other than some vague and general averages. Searching online I've only found a [single person](https://www.rootusers.com/cloudflare-argo-benchmark/) who posted their benchmark before and after enabling it.

Comment: There's a reasonable benchmark posted here (https://www.firstpractica.com/457/cloudflare-argo-test-drive/) which indicates approx 33% improvement in server response time (TTFB I think) - similar to what Cloudflare is claiming.